# Check if username already exists, no ajax or php, just pure js

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function submit() 
        {
            var ul = document.getElementById("names");
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

            var i = 0, flag = 0;
            var allNames = [];
            if (allNames.length == 0) 
            {
                allNames[0] = name;
            }
            else 
            {
                if (allNames.includes(name))
                {
                    alert("Name already exists.");
                    return -1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    allNames[i++] = name;
                }
            }
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = name;

            ul.appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById("name").value = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    <div>
        <h2>Usernames</h2>
        <ul id="names"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to check if a username already exists and therefore block the new entry, only using javascript?

I've tried also moving the initialization of the array outside of the function but it doesn't work that way either...

Comment: Without PHP how would you check?

Comment: There should be some way to store the usernames. Where you will store all the usernames

Comment: If you just want this to only be used in browsers memory, you just need to change the scope of `allNames`, currently you have it scoped to the submit, meaning it's only available during the submit function.

Comment: Where is your data going to come from?

Comment: Removing `allNames` from the submit function didn't change anything before, but somehow it works now, thanks Keith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just declare the `allNames` variable outside of your function. You currently create it with an empty array each time you call the submit function.

You also have an issue because your `i` is set to 0 every time. Just use `.push` if it is not included (*instead of trying to specify the index*).

```js
var allNames = [];

function submit() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("names");
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

  if (allNames.includes(name)) {
    alert("Name already exists.");
    return -1;
  } else {
    allNames.push(name);
  }

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = name;

  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("name").value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<div>
  <h2>Usernames</h2>
  <ul id="names"></ul>
</div>
```